# Linking tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to know how to link two tables in a php/mysql set up then rank the results?
Here is my situation.

I have a stories table:

```
storyid
writerid
title
story
submitdate
```

and a votes table

```
voteid
userid
storyid
vote
```

I store a vote up as a 1 and a vote down as a -1
I am looking for a way to join these two table then rank/sort the stories by the number of votes they recieve. 
I am open to any ideas about how to do so or a different possible database schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to keep the names of my tables singular.  It's not a "Stories" table; it's a "Story" table with multiple rows.

A vote can only be attributed to a single story, so it's a one-to-many relationship between the two.  I'd put the foreign key in the votes table and let it point out the story it's associated with.  Change your schema if you agree: remove the `voteid` from the `story` table and make `storyid` in `vote` a foreign key to the `story` table.

But with that said, perhaps you can try a query like this:

```
select stories.storyid, sum(vote=-1) as down, sum(vote=1) as up
from stories
inner join votes on (stories.storyid = votes.storyid)
group by stories.storyid
```

Corrected per ypercube's comment below.

Comment: This is a good basis for a solution. However, it returns the total number of votes for that story whereas i would prefer having a count for the number of votes up and a count for the number of votes down.

Comment: After looking at some SQL functions I decided to use the sum() function. It is essentially what I would have calculated had I received the separate values for the votes. I used the above query except I substituted `count(*)` with `sum(votes.vote)`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Drew: Use `SUM(vote)` instead of `COUNT(*)`. If you want both up and down votes separately, use `COUNT(vote=1) AS up` and `COUNT(vote=-1) AS down`

Comment: If ypercube would make his comment an answer, I think it'd be justice if you'd accept his contribution as the correct one.

Comment: @duffymo I was thinking the same thing but with his edits I believe your answer works perfectly. I appreciate you giving him credit though.

Comment: If he does decide to change do feel free to change your upvote and acceptance to him.